# How to obtain bucket name from cloudwatch event?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda function that is triggered by the cloudwatch event "createbucket"
when trying to execute the lambda function which is;

```
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Get bucket name from the S3 event
print(event)

    bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']
print(bucket_name) 

#        if record['eventName'] == "CreateBucket":
#            bucket =record['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']
#            print(bucket)
#            bucket_name =bucket
    # Create a bucket policy
bucket_policy =json.dumps({
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                        "AES256",
                        "aws:kms"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::{bucket_name}/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                    }
            }
        } ] })


    # Set the new policy
s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)
```

I get an error that has to deal with

`module initialization error: name 'bucket_name' is not defined`
any ideas?
I must get the name of the bucket picked up by the create bucket event yet it never seems to pass through to the lambda function. Is there any way I can pass the name of the new bucket to the function?

EDIT
The new error I get is

```
{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      11,
      "lambda_handler",
      "bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "errorMessage": "'detail'"
}
```

CW Event config:

```
  "source": [
    "aws.s3"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateBucket"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

In addition to the indent issues, this appears to be the result of an error from using the default Lambda event template which does not match the syntax for CloudWatch events.

**Original**

This is an indentation issue. The `s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)` function call would have been executed outside of the `lambda_handler`

I have fixed the indentation of the Lambda function below

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Get bucket name from the S3 event
    print(event)

    bucket_name = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']
    print(bucket_name) 

#        if record['eventName'] == "CreateBucket":
#            bucket =record['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']
#            print(bucket)
#            bucket_name =bucket
    # Create a bucket policy
    bucket_policy =json.dumps({
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedAtRest",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "StringNotEquals": {
                        "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": [
                            "AES256",
                            "aws:kms"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "MustBeEncryptedInTransit",
                "Effect": "Deny",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "s3:*",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}".format(bucket_name),
                    "arn:aws:s3:::{}/*".format(bucket_name)
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "Bool": {
                        "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                        }
                }
            } ] })


    # Set the new policy
    s3.put_bucket_policy(Bucket=bucket_name, Policy=bucket_policy)
```

Comment: I included the new error that shows up. should I also note that I am using EventBridge (Cloudwatch events) as the trigger? should I be using something else?

Comment: Could you share your cloudwatch event configuration?

Comment: I added it in at the bottom.

Comment: Just waiting for this to trigger now, have made a couple of S3 buckets

Comment: This has triggered fine for me for the event although it does return the error "An error occurred (MalformedPolicy) when calling the PutBucketPolicy operation: Policy has invalid resource". Are you receiving this error from an actual CloudWatch event trigger?

Comment: I receive the error when I use "test" in the lambda function editor, and when i test by creating buckets and seeing if the policy is written inside or not, it is never there. Should I wait longer for the bucket policies to appear in my new buckets?

Comment: Right, ok so theres 2 points here. The test event is actually using JSON you specify so you should replace the event with the one from the documentation. Secondly there is an error with the JSON policy as there is no resource named "{bucket_policy}". I have fixed this for the function.

Comment: Please note it may take a few minutes for the trigger to apply as CloudTrail based events tend to suffer delay upto 10 minutes